# SVG position from x="0" y="0"

Tags: svg

I try to write a text element in an SVG from `x="50%" y="0"`.

My text is not appears and I don't know why.

Here is my SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="900px" height="706" viewBox="0 0 900 706" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text x="50%" y="0" text-anchor="middle" fill="#f00" text-anchor="middle" style="font-family: DINPro; font-size: 28px;">xxxx</text>
</svg>
```

I am not know the `font-size` it will be dynamically. If I am give `y="20"` then my text appears. But why is it?

As I [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Positions) here, the `0 0` it the left top corner of the SVG.

Why is it? As you see, the the with and the height and the `viewBox` is the same.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Add an dominant-baseline attribute to your text element and set to hanging.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="900px" height="706" viewBox="0 0 900 706" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text x="50%" y="0" fill="#f00" text-anchor="middle" style="font-family: DINPro; font-size: 28px;" dominant-baseline="hanging">xxxx</text>
</svg>
```

You have three options to change this:

> **dominant-baseline** – used to determine or re-determine a scaled-baseline-table
>
> **alignment-baseline** – specifies which baseline is to be aligned with the
>   corresponding baseline of the parent
>
> **baseline-shift** – allows repositioning of the dominant-baseline relative to the dominant-baseline of the parent

See this post for more information about this: http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-text-baseline-alignment/

Answer (score 0):

Per the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#FontsTablesBaselines)

> The Y coordinate of the bottom of a roman capital letter is usually zero. And the descenders on lowercase roman letters have negative coordinate values.

Answer (score 0):

On a text element, y is the element bottom position. 
In your case, the text printed outside of the viewbox.

Try to set your y to 20.